# Fetch the objectId from Parse.ParseObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how to obtain the objectId from an query. What i am trying to accomplish is that I want to know if a object with a specific username and password exists in my class and then if yes, get the objectId and save it in my Unity game!

Here is how I am trying to do so with no luck:

```
void OnClick(){

        PrimeAI.ShowSpinner();
        LoginUsername = GameObject.Find("UsernameLogin").GetComponent<UIInput>().value;
        LoginPassword = GameObject.Find("PasswordLogin").GetComponent<UIInput>().value;

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Players")
            .WhereEqualTo("playername", LoginUsername)
            .WhereEqualTo("password", Constant.Md5Sum(LoginPassword));
        query.CountAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            int count = t.Result;
            if(count == 1){
                GetUserData(LoginUsername);
            } else {
                LoginError = true;
            }   
        });

    }

    public void GetUserData(string UserName){

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Players")
            .WhereEqualTo("playername", UserName);
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

            OnlyOnce = true;

            foreach (var result in results) {
                print("Here: "+result["objectId"]);
            }

        });

    }
```

It works fine until the foreach loop... How can I accomplish this and what am i doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do a Find rather than a CountAsync. Then just access the objectID from the returned object. If you are concerned about moving the whole object when you don't need it, use selectKeys to select only the attributes you want.

-Bob

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var result in results) {
    print("Here: "+ result.objectId);
}
```